Jest mock jquery that loaded as adm by requireJS
I have a JS script where using RequireJS loading jquery and using it in this way
window.define(['jquery','sf'],
    function ($, sf) {
    let resultObj = {}
    resultObj.id = setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            'url': URL,
            'type': 'GET',
            'success': function (response) {
            },
            'error': function () {
            }
        });
    })

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).ajaxSend(function () {
           
        })
    });
    return {
        start: function (options) {
            resultObj.id(options);
        }
    }

})

i have tried the test case in this way
const jQ = jest.requireActual("jquery");

const ready = jest.fn((cb) => {
    return Promise.resolve(cb());
});

const ajaxSend = jest.fn((cb) => {
    return Promise.resolve(cb());
});

const jQuery = jQ;
jQuery.ready = ready;
jQuery.ajaxSend = ajaxSend;


Object.defineProperty(window, 'define', {
    writable: true,
    value: (query, cb) => {
        global.definecallback = cb(jQuery);
    }
});

describe("test suite", () => {
    test("testing ", async () => {
    });

});

I am getting an error that jquery is module is not found because it is loaded by requireJS. Is there any way i can proceed please help
